# Trying to get hours and minutes of a date in IONIC : getHours is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I am trying to get the hours and the minutes of a date in ionic and got an error.

here is my code from the .html file :

```
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]='timeEntered1' picker-format="h:mm"></ion-datetime>
  <ion-button (click)="getTime()"></ion-button>
```

Then inside my .ts file I have this :

```
timeEntered1 = new Date();

constructor() {}

getTime() {
  console.log(this.timeEntered1.getHours());
}
```

and my error is :

> this.timeEntered1.getHours is not a function

Comment: Try with  console.log (new Date(this.timeEntered1).getHours());

Comment: I got a Nan in the console.. @MikNiller

Answer (score 0):

What ionic provides for you in this case, when you pick a time, here for example `2:03` you get an output of

```
{
    "hour": {
        "text": "2",
        "value": 2,
        "columnIndex": 0
    },
    "minute": {
        "text": "03",
        "value": 3,
        "columnIndex": 1
    }
}
```

So you don't need to do `getHours()`, they are all stored in your model. So do:

```
timeEntered1 = <any>{};

getTime() {
  // outputs 2 and 3
  console.log(this.timeEntered1.hour.value, this.timeEntered1.minute.value);
}
```

Comment: I got :  Property 'hour' does not exist on type 'Date'.. @AJT82

Comment: sure, the issue is that you are declaring `timeEntered1 = new Date()`, so the types don't match. So how do you really want to use this button? What is the purpose. When you click it, should it set the time, or after setting the time you click button to get the hours & minutes?

Comment: declaring timeEntered as `timeEntered1 = {}` solves the typing issue.

Comment: I'd like to get hours and minutes of my time. Still does not work, now hour and minute are underline and I got timeEntered1 = {} @ATJ82

Comment: Please replicate issue, works fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-y2dfkb?file=src/app/home/home.page.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `<button>`-tag. :)

```
 <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]='timeEntered1' picker-format="h:mm"></ion-datetime>
    <button ion-button (click)="getTime()"></button>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jkhwaw

Comment: Sure there is `ion-button` tag. Your sample is using ionic 3, whereas OP is using ionic 4, the syntax is different.